# Why the services is not a list in docker-compose files

Tags: docker, automation, yaml

I am learning and testing docker with yaml. And I have created a simple docker-compose.yml file as:

```
version: "3"
services:
     redis:
        image: redis

     click-counter:
        image: kodekloud/click-counter

        ports:
        -   8080:5000
        links:
        -   redis:redis
```

My question: Are the services under option services list(redis and click-counter). Then appending a dash should work but is not working.

```
version: "3"
services:
     - redis:
        image: redis

     - click-counter:
        image: kodekloud/click-counter

        ports:
        -   8080:5000
        links:
        -   redis:redis
```

This throws errors in terminal as:

```
RROR: In file './docker-compose.yml', service must be a mapping, not an array.
```

Can any assist on the this.

Answer (score 0):

`services` is a map in terms of Docker Compose YAML definition. It allows enforcing no duplicated services.

When you add `-` in front of the name of each service, `services` is going to be a list in terms of YAML definition. And therefore is not what is expected by Docker.

The first `docker-compose` file you have has the correct format for defining `services`.

```
version: "3"
services:
  redis:
    ...

  click-counter:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In Docker Compose, the services are defined as a mapping (key-value pairs) under the 'services' key, not as a list. Each service is key, with its configuration as the corresponding value. That's why your first example works and the second one doesn't.
When you add a dash (-) before a service name, you're trying to define it as an item in a list, which is not the correct syntax for defining services in Docker Compose. The correct syntax is to simply list the service names without a dash, as in your first example.
So, your docker-compose.yml file should look like this:

```
version: "3"
services:
     redis:
        image: redis

     click-counter:
        image: kodekloud/click-counter
        ports:
        -   8080:5000
        links:
        -   redis:redis
```

This is the correct way to define services in Docker Compose.

Comment: Why did you post this answer? What does it add that the other answer doesn't have?